# Need better implementation to find given IP address from list of IP range

Tags: java

There is a table contains startIP, endIp and all other data related to location etc.

On application start-up whole table data is cached to reduce query. Now when user connect to application we got frammed IP (that is client IP) and need to find the Ip range from the cache.

So, What will be the better implementation of the cache?

Currently I've  implemented like:

```
ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, String>> cache;
```

where outer map key is like : **startIP_endIP**

i.e 10.115.1.10_10.115.1.240

and outer map value (inner map) contains the single row of table.

There is one advantage to implement key as above is that I can use **ConcurrentNavigableMap.subMap()** method to reduce the iteration.

Find below scenario

- Got client IP i.e(10.115.1.10)
- Splitting the string by (.) and trying to find the submap from the cache
- now iterating over submap.keySet() to find exact IPRange.

please find below code snippet:

```
System.out.println("==============================================");
    System.out.println("clientIP: " + clientIP);  // Client IP address
    ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, Object> subMap = null;
    String clientIPTokens[] = new String[4];
    clientIPTokens[0] = clientIP; // 10.115.1.10
    clientIPTokens[1] = clientIP.substring(0, clientIP.lastIndexOf(".")); // 10.115.1
    clientIPTokens[2] = clientIP.substring(0, clientIP.indexOf(".", clientIP.indexOf(".")+1)); // 10.115
    clientIPTokens[3] = clientIP.substring(0,clientIP.indexOf(".") ); //10

    ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, Object> packageMap = null;

    boolean isValid = false;
    for(String tokens : clientIPTokens){
        subMap = MapCache.getSubMapByPreffix(COLLECTION_NAME, tokens);  // got submap
        System.out.println("tokens: " + tokens + ", subMap: " + subMap);
        if(subMap!=null && subMap.size()>0){
            for(String key : subMap.keySet()){
                isValid = checkIPInMap((ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, String>) subMap.get(key),clientIP);
                if(isValid) // ip range found for the client ip (Got the single row)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(isValid)
            break;
    }

    // When no match found need to iterate over whole cache
    if(!isValid && MapCache.getMap()!=null && MapCache.getMap().containsKey(COLLECTION_NAME)){  
        packageMap = MapCache.getMap().get(COLLECTION_NAME);
        isValid = checkIPInFullMap(packageMap, clientIP);
    }
```

I'll have around 650 entry in table so how can I better implement the cache or cache key so that searching will be easier.

***So, Bottom line is :***

I have one IP and list of IP-Range(start-ip, end-ip). And need to find in which IP-Range it will fall. But have to iterate over whole list or (sub list) and need to check

```java
public static boolean isValidRange(String ipStart, String ipEnd,
                String ipToCheck){
            try {
                long ipLo = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName(ipStart));
                long ipHi = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName(ipEnd));
                long ipToTest = ipToLong(InetAddress.getByName(ipToCheck));
                return (ipToTest >= ipLo && ipToTest <= ipHi);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                //throw new Exception();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I believe this logic must require some improvement!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses can be compared as numbers (if your ranges is correct).

Try to convert ipStart and ipEnd to 32 bit number (I prefer long for it to avoid signed comparison tricks). Add a start and end mark to this number (simply in lower number bits, if you use longs) and store it to any kind of sorted list or set.

Now pick clientIP and convert it to same kind of number. Search your list for two closest numbers, above and below client IP and check start/end flags to ensure you fail between start and end (in range), not end and start (between ranges).

I think it is fastest and clearest method for your task.

**EDIT:**

Yes, your check logic is correct.
I propose whole solution for your main problem -- finding range by ip.

Some pseudocode:

```
//setup:
TreeSet<Long> ranges = new TreeSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < rangesCount; ++i) {
  ranges.add(toLong(rangeStart[i]) << 1);
  ranges.add((toLong(rangeEnd[i]) << 1) + 1);
}

//check:
long client = toLong(clientIp) << 1;
Long floorIp = ranges.floor(client);
Long ceilIp = ranges.ceiling(client);

if(floorIp == null || ceilIp == null) {
  //outside any ranges
} else {
  if(floorIp & 1 == 0 && ceilIp & 1 == 1) {
    //in range floorIp-ceilIp
  } else {
    //between ranges
  }
}
```

Of course, ranges cannot intersect in any way for this.

You can also keep range number in this structure by mixing it into long number between ip and start-end marker.

```
long marker = (ip << 16 + (short) range_id) << 1 + startEndMark;
long floorIp = ranges.floor(clientIp << 17 + MAX_SHORT << 1);
long ceilIp = ranges.ceiling(clientIp << 17);
```

Small comment for last line:
We need `MAX_SHORT << 1` for correct handling start edge of interval, because 
`0xIP_IP_IP_IP_IDID_0 >= 0xIP_IP_IP_IP_0000_0`, but `0xIP_IP_IP_IP_IDID_0 <= 0xIP_IP_IP_IP_FF_FF_0`. For end edge: `0xIP_IP_IP_IP_0000_0 <= 0xIP_IP_IP_IP_IDID_1`.

Or you can put sorted ranges to array and use array index as range number as well.

**EDIT 2:**

Also there is a True Java Way: Create object for IP and range id (and start-end markers, etc). Define Comparator (or implement Comparable) and store this objects in sorted set or map instead of bit-mixed longs.

Comment: Please find update code for **isValidRange** method. I'm not doing any string comparison.